# how can i fetch data from database and fill <input type=“text”> when page opens

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a site that displays massages from users stored in a database. what i want is when i click the reply link beside each message a new page must load and the details from each message must be filled in the  and how to i get the specific data for a particulate row after i loop through.

```
<?php 
$dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","technoage");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"technoage") or die ("database not found!!!");

$r = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM messages LIMIT $startrow,10 "); // Run the query.
if($r) { // If it ran OK, display the Table header.
    echo '<table class="table"> <tr><td><b>Name of sender</b></td><td><b>Senders Details</b></td><td><b>Message</b></td><td><b>Reply To Massage</b><td/></tr>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    { 
        echo'<tr><td>'.'Name: '.$row['name'].'</td><td> '.'Email: '.$row['email_address'] .'<br>Subject: '.$row['message_subject'].'<br>Phone: '.$row['phone'].'<br>Date Sent: '.$row['date_sent']. '</td><td>'.'Message: '.$row['message'].'</td><td><a     href="#">Reply</a></td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

when the reply link is clicked a page must load with the details of the massage clicked.

the reply file is

```
<?php 
    $dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","technoage");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"technoage") or die ("database not found!!!");

    // Run the query.

    echo'<form method="post" action="includes/insert.php">';
    echo'<label for="name">Name:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>';
    echo'<label for="email">E-mail Address:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>';
    echo'<label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>';
    echo'<label for="text">Message Subject:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="message_subject" id="message_subject"></textarea><br>';
    echo'<label for="text">Message:</label><br>';
    echo'<textarea class="text" name="message" id="text"></textarea><br>';
    echo'<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" />';
    echo'</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: Please don't use `SELECT *`. Better `SELECT id, name, phone.... FROM ...`

You can generate a reply link with the primary key of your databasetable. (e.g. Id)

```
echo '<a href="reply.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Reply</a>';
```

Make sure, that `id` is always a integer and not userinput that could generate bad links.

Answer (score 0):

add value attribute for form field like this

```
echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" value="'.$row['name'].'" /><br>';
```

and add the same attribute for other fields accordingly.

Comment: thanks that works but i have one more problem. am using a while loop to go through the recodes and echo them out limiting 5. each record echoed a replay link is also echoed. how do i get the data for a particular row that i click to be displayed in reply form. hope that is enough information.

Comment: @NanguHaci You probably could use `SELECT users FROM messages` for example, instead of `SELECT * FROM messages` or `SELECT * FROM messages AS users`

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.

1st Page missing points:
1. No Form Declared

Modified Code:

```
<?php 
$dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","technoage");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"technoage") or die ("database not found!!!");
}

$r = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM messages LIMIT $startrow,10 "); // Run the query.
if($r) { // If it ran OK, display the Table header.
echo "<form method='post' action='target_pagelink.php' target='_blank'>";
echo '<table class="table"> 
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name of sender</b></td>
            <td><b>Senders Details</b></td>
            <td><b>Message</b></td>
            <td><b>Reply To Massage</b><td/>
        </tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{ 
echo'<tr><td>'.'Name: '.$row['name'].
    '</td><td> '.'Email: '.$row['email_address'] .
    '<br>Subject: '.$row['message_subject'].
    '<br>Phone: '.$row['phone'].
    '<br>Date Sent: '.$row['date_sent']. 
    '</td><td>'.'Message: '.$row['message'].
    '</td><td>'."
    <input type='hidden' name='Name' value=".$row['name']." >
    <input type='hidden' name='Email' value=".$row['email_address']." >
    <input type='hidden' name='Subject' value=".$row['message_subject']." >
    <input type='hidden' name='Phone' value=".$row['phone']." >
    <input type='hidden' name='DateS' value=".$row['date_sent']." >
    <input type='hidden' name='Message' value=".$row['message']." >
    <input type='submit' value='Reply' >
    </td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

2nd(Reply File) Page missing points:
1. No element declared to accept input parameters

```
<?php 
    $dbcon=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","technoage");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"technoage") or die ("database not found!!!");

    // Run the query.

    if(
        isset($_POST['name']) &&
        isset($_POST['email_address']) &&
        isset($_POST['message_subject']) &&
        isset($_POST['phone']) &&
        isset($_POST['date_sent']) &&
        isset($_POST['message']) 
    ){
    echo'<form method="post" action="includes/insert.php">';
    echo'<label for="name">Name:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" value='.$_POST['name'].'/><br>';
    echo'<label for="email">E-mail Address:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" value='.$_POST['email_address'].' /><br>';
    echo'<label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="phone" id="phone" value='.$_POST['phone'].' /><br>';
    echo'<label for="text">Message Subject:</label><br>';
    echo'<input type="text" class="text" name="message_subject" id="message_subject" value='.$_POST['message_subject'].' ></textarea><br>';
    echo'<label for="text">Message:</label><br>';
    echo'<textarea class="text" name="message" id="text" >'.$_POST['message'].'</textarea><br>';
    echo'<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" />';
    echo'</form>';
    }
?>
```